# PrerenderIO doesn't render via https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, cloudflare, prerender

I run [prerenderIO](https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node) (nodeJS) custom server on port 3000 on EC2 instance on AWS (Ubuntu). It works fine when from terminal I run:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/http://mydomainname.com/path
```

but when I run with `https` it doesn't work:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/https://mydomainname.com/path
```

`http` and `https` urls are live and working fine so I can access both and page renders just fine:

```
http://mydomainname.com/path
https://mydomainname.com/path
```

Only when I run it thru prerenderIO server `https` doesnt come back (I think I’m getting 504 error, will double check later)

I’m also behind [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) and am using their flexible SSL. 
As both URL’s are working fine my best guess is that that some configuration is needed in prerenderIO. I would really appreciate any advice as been stuck with this for last 2 days.

BTW even though I'm having trouble setting this up I must say that both PrerenderIO and Cloudflare are absolutely amazing!

EDIT:
I should probably add that I tried adding:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('protocol', 'https'));
```

with no luck unfortunately.

Also when I run:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/https://google.com
```

It works just fine.

I will post exact result from `curl -v` later

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with SSL certificate validation, but you aren't providing any error messages or logs or even a good description of what exactly is happening when you run the command that "doesn't work".

Comment: If you are using PhantomJS 1.9.8 locally, 1.9.8 is known to have issues with SNI so that might point to why HTTPS isn't working. We use a compiled version of PhantomJS 2.0 that doesn't have SNI issues.